# Android Room search and filter using relations, query multiple tables

Tags: android, sql, android-room

Repo is below if you want to issue a pull request please include comments.

I've created a Room database for my PokemonApp I want to be able to filter and search the database based on Pokemon name and Pokemon types.

I have a table for my Pokemon entity, a table for the PokemonType entity and a junction table for the PokemonTypeJoin entity, I also have a data class PokemonWithTypes which embeds a Pokemon entity and defines a relation between this and a list of PokemonType entities.

Pokemon entity:

```
    @TypeConverters(RoomStringListConverter::class)
    @Entity
    data class Pokemon(
        @NotNull
        @PrimaryKey
        @ColumnInfo(name = POKEMON_ID)
        var id: Int,
    
        @ColumnInfo(name = POKEMON_NAME)
        var name: String,
    
        @ColumnInfo(name = POKEMON_URL)
        var url: String,
    
        @ColumnInfo(name = POKEMON_WEIGHT)
        val weight: Int,
    
        @ColumnInfo(name = POKEMON_HEIGHT)
        val height: Int,
    
        @ColumnInfo(name = POKEMON_SPECIES)
        var species: String,
    
        @ColumnInfo(name = POKEMON_MOVES)
        val moves: List<String>
    
    ) 

    const val POKEMON_ID: String = "pokemon_id"
    const val POKEMON_NAME: String = "pokemon_name"
    const val POKEMON_URL: String = "pokemon_url"
    const val POKEMON_HEIGHT: String = "pokemon_height"
    const val POKEMON_WEIGHT: String = "pokemon_weight"
    const val POKEMON_MOVES: String = "pokemon_moves"
    const val POKEMON_SPECIES: String = "pokemon_species"
```

PokemonType entity:

```
    @Entity
    data class PokemonType (
    
        @NotNull
        @PrimaryKey
        @ColumnInfo(name = POKEMON_TYPE_ID)
        var id: Int,
    
        @ColumnInfo(name = POKEMON_TYPE_NAME)
        var name: String,
    
        @ColumnInfo(name = POKEMON_TYPE_SLOT)
        var slot: Int
    
    )

    const val POKEMON_TYPE_ID: String = "type_id"
    const val POKEMON_TYPE_NAME: String = "type_name"
    const val POKEMON_TYPE_SLOT: String = "type_slot"
```

PokemonTypesJoin entity:

```
    @Entity(primaryKeys = [POKEMON_ID, POKEMON_TYPE_ID])
    class PokemonTypesJoin(
        @NotNull
        @ColumnInfo(name = POKEMON_ID, index = true)
        val pokemon_id: Int,
    
        @NotNull
        @ColumnInfo(name = POKEMON_TYPE_ID, index = true)
        val pokemon_type_id: Int
    
    )
    
    const val POKEMON_ID: String = "id"
    const val POKEMON_TYPE_ID: String = "type_id"
```

PokemonWithTypes class

```
    data class PokemonWithTypes(
        @Embedded
        val pokemon: Pokemon,
        @Relation(
            parentColumn = Pokemon.POKEMON_ID,
            entity = PokemonType::class,
            entityColumn = PokemonType.POKEMON_TYPE_ID,
            associateBy = Junction(
                value = PokemonTypesJoin::class,
                parentColumn = PokemonTypesJoin.POKEMON_ID,
                entityColumn = PokemonTypesJoin.POKEMON_TYPE_ID
            )
        )
        val types: List<PokemonType>
    )
```

given this structure I can get and search by pokemon_name all PokemonWithTypes using the following query:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM pokemon WHERE pokemon_name LIKE :search ORDER BY pokemon_id ASC")
fun getPokemonWithTypes(search: String?): LiveData<List<PokemonWithTypes>>
```

but how can I now add a filter (list of string) that only returns PokemonWithTypes where any of PokemonWithTypes.types matches a given type in the filters list?

So given 3 Pokemon (some data removed for brevity)

```
PokemonWithTypes(pokemon=Pokemon(id=1, name=bulbasaur, types=[PokemonType(id=4, name=poison, slot=2), PokemonType(id=12, name=grass, slot=1)])
PokemonWithTypes(pokemon=Pokemon(id=4, name=charmander, types=[PokemonType(id=10, name=fire, slot=2), PokemonType(id=12, name=grass, slot=1)])
PokemonWithTypes(pokemon=Pokemon(id=7, name=squirtle, types=[PokemonType(id=11, name=water, slot=2), PokemonType(id=12, name=grass, slot=1)])
```

I currently get all Pokemon and can search by pokemon_name but I'd like to be able to show just water types or just grass types any ideas welcome,

I tried just filtering on a string instead of a list of string with a query like this

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM pokemon, pokemonType WHERE type_name LIKE :filter AND pokemon_name LIKE :search ORDER BY pokemon_id ASC")
fun getPokemonWithTypes(search: String?, filter: String): LiveData<List<PokemonWithTypes>>
```

but it didn't work

you can check out the full thing here https://github.com/martipello/PokeApp/tree/add_filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the @Relation annotation is not designed for that use case. It is only designed to return ALL related types, not a filtered subset. I think you have 3 options:

1. Just filter it with Kotlin: `pokemonWithTypes.filter { it.types.contains("GRASS") }`. I assume you don't have more than 10000 records of pokemons so performance isn't an issue.
2. Write a join query. I think that's more effort for negligible performance gain.
3. Use database Views as per: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65509934. This is more static and you'll have to write a view for every type.

Comment: Thanks for this I'll be filtering it in the view model

Comment: Hey need help here-->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63266686/how-do-i-remove-row-from-recyclerview-using-room

Comment: I am really interested in 2. How would the returning pojo looks like with a custom join (no @Relation) Thanks